# Passing multipart form data from python to django server with both file and data

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-requests

I have a Django server and a react frontend application. I hava an endpoint that receives both data and file object. The javascript version of the api client is working fine and it looks something like this.

```
const address = `${baseAddress}/${endpoint}`;
const multipartOptions = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${filename}`,
    'X-CSRFToken': getCSRFToken(),
  },
};
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);

const json = JSON.stringify(metadata);
const blob = new Blob([json], {
  type: 'application/json',
});
formData.append('metadata', blob);
return axios.post(address, formData, multipartOptions);
```

So as you can see I am using a blob to add metadata to my form data and passing it to the server.
Printing the `request.data` in the server gives me something like this.

```
<QueryDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: admin_12183.zip (application/zip)>], 'metadata': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: blob (application/json)>]}>
```

So I can access both `request.data.get('file')` and `request.data.get('metadata')` on my django server.

Now I have to do something similar in `python`. I tried using `requests` to get the stuff right, but I don't get two separate keys in the `QueryDict`. The python code looks like this.

```
with open("file.zip", "rb") as fp:
    with open("metadata.json", "rb") as meta:
        file_headers = {
            **headers,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryjzAXwA7GGcenPlPk',
        }
        data = {
            "file": "",
        }
        files = { 
            'file': ("file.zip", fp, "application/zip"),
            'metadata': ("blob", meta, "application/json"),
        }
        response = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}/api/endpoint", data=data, files=files, headers=file_headers)
        print(response.status_code)
```

If I do not send in both files and data at the same time, I get nothing in `request.data`. And if I send both of them, I am getting both of the data in a single key, that corresponds to whatever key I have in the `data` variable.

The server has this code in it

```
 def post(self, request,  *args, **kwargs):
    file_obj = request.data.get('file')
    metadata = request.data.get('metadata')
    # both are empty if either one of files or data is not sent from the client
    # if both are sent, then request.data has only one key, with everything inside of it
    # works fine with the javascript code
```

I think I am missing something very small and trivial.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was adding a content-type in my header and that is what was causing all the issues. The working code looks like this

```
file_headers = {
    **headers,
    # make sure there is no content type in the header
}
files = { 
    'file': ("file.zip", shape, "application/zip"),
    'metadata': ("blob", meta, "application/json"),
}
response = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}/api/shapefiles", files=files, headers=file_headers)
print(response.text, response.status_code)
```